# How to design an ETL framework with tokenized data in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently working in the Financial Sector and we are considering moving to AWS Redshift for our Data Warehouse solution.  The Security rules require us to mask/tokenize any Confidential/PII data before we take them to the AWS cloud.

Any thoughts on the feasibility of designing such a solution (to include a tokenization system)? 
How would referential integrity be handled?

We would like to do some analytics and aggregation of data in AWS for building analytics ready data.

Answer (score 0):

> Any thoughts on the feasibility of designing such a solution (to include a tokenization system)?

there are multiple tools, every reasonable ETL system should have the capability.

> How would referential integrity be handled?

avoid using any PII as reference key nd the tokens don't need to be random

For better answer you should be more specific in the question

Answer (score 0):

As you load data onto AWS, you can have the data published an SNS topic, and have the topic mask the sensitive data for you, in real time.

This data protection feature was first introduced to SNS in September 2022 in public preview, and announced as generally available (GA) in November 2023. This feature supports sensitive data auditing, blocking, masking, and redaction. For more information, check out:

- SNS developer guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-data-protection.html
- AWS compute blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-message-data-protection-for-amazon-sns/

Here's a sample data protection policy, which you can attach to an SNS topic. This policy instructs SNS to mask any `CreditCardNumber` in the payload, using the `#` character:

```
{
  "Name": "__example_data_protection_policy",
  "Description": "Example data protection policy",
  "Version": "2021-06-01",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "DataDirection": "Inbound",
      "Principal": [
        "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/ExampleUser"
      ],
      "DataIdentifier": [
        "arn:aws:dataprotection::aws:data-identifier/CreditCardNumber"
      ],
      "Operation": {
        "Deidentify": {
          "MaskConfig": {
            "MaskWithCharacter": "#"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's the data de-identification results:

```
// original message
My credit card number is 4539894458086459

// delivered message
My credit card number is ################
```